# Cakephp many to many relationship between products and orders

Tags: cakephp, relationship

So currently I have two table products and orders. Relationship between them is many to many. Code I used in Model Product.php is

```
        public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array
( 
    'Order'=>array
    ( 
        'joinTable' => 'ordersproducts', 
        'unique' => true, 
        'foreignKey' => 'productID',
        'associationForeignKey'  => 'orderID', 
        'order'=>'productID ASC'
    )
);
```

Code I used in Model Order.php is

```
        public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array
( 
    'Product'=>array
    ( 
        'joinTable' => 'ordersproducts', 
        'unique' => true, 
        'foreignKey' => 'orderID',
        'associationForeignKey'  => 'productID', 
        'order'=>'productID ASC'
    )
);
```

Current function is add() which is admin can add order for customer. Function code in Order Controller is

```
public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) 
    {
        if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) 
        {               
                $this->request->data['Product']['Product'] = array(); 
                foreach($this->data['Product']['checkbox'] as $k=>$v) 
                { 
                    if ($v) $this->request->data['Product']['Product'][] = $k; 

                }   

                //$this->Order->create();
                if ($this->Order->saveAll($this->request->data)) {
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The order has been saved'),'default',array('class' => 'good'));
                    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
                } else {
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The order could not be saved. Please, try again.'),'default',array('class' => 'error'));
                }

        }
    }
    $products = $this->Order->Product->find('list',array('fields'=>array('id','name'))); 
    $this->set(compact('products'));

    $customers= $this->Order->Customer->find('list',array('order'=>'cutomer_name ASC','fields'=>array('id','cutomer_name')));
    $this->set(compact('customers')); 


}
```

View for the adding order is:

```
    foreach ($products as $id=>$label) 
        { 
            echo "<tr>"; 
            echo "<td class='heading'>".$label."</td>"; 
            echo "<td class='data'>"; 
            echo $this->Form->input("Product.checkbox.$id", array('label'=>'','legend'=>false,'type'=>'checkbox',)); 
            echo "</td>"; 
            echo "</tr>"; 
        }
```

As you can see I used checkbox for product list. Now I would like to know where should I add quantity and what changes do I need to make in Model relationship. I am not sure how to do it

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is to use the 'with' parameter for your HABTM relationship:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasandbelongstomany-habtm

The 'with' parameter should reference an 'OrderItem' with foreign keys for order and product, with extra parameters for quantity, unit price, item name and whatever else you want to add.

Be careful with orders, you need to ensure that you don't normalise the data too much, as if your product changes price later on you don't want to lose the amount that the customer paid for this order item.